# Correctly retrieving the tx_pubkey from a transaction

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, transaction-data, source, tx-extra, transaction-key

I found, in the code, an [example](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp#L11501) of a function that retrieves a public key from a transaction. The comments say that because of a previous bug, the tx may contain more than one public key.

Do I understand correctly that this bug has been fixed, and in order to look for the key in new transactions, I don’t need to check if there may be several keys?

Could somebody please clarify whether it is guaranteed that the variable `two_found` here, will always be true in all new transactions?

Comment: It will not normally happen, but extra is a freeform field, so it's not guaranteed.

Comment: It's not "freeform" [[ref](https://cryptonote.org/cns/cns005.txt)], and there are a couple of normal scenarios more than one key can be in tx_extra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tx_extra` can contain any number of items. The field is documented here: https://cryptonote.org/cns/cns005.txt

Therefore it can contain 0..N public keys. Usually there is just one public key in it (the tx public key), but there could be more. So do not rely on there just being one, you have to parse the field and respond accordingly.

One such example of a case where there can be more than one public key in the tx extra is for multi-destination transfers involving one or more subaddresses. I also seem to recall that multisig transfers add additional keys in the field.

Comment: I see, thanks. Are there any reasonable situations where there may be several public keys in a transaction (not by mistake)?

Comment: Yes. [multi-destination transfers involving one or more subaddresses](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/581994b61c9b8b530629b2dbc2e7ddd3b30b12b4/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp#L1815) is one for example.

Comment: IIRC multisig also makes use of multiple keys in extra.